# Zoo Visitor not outputting all members

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, transcribe, zoo

I'm using EE 2.8.1 and Zoo Visitor 1.3.32.

I'm trying to output a list of all members using

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist}

    {title}

{/exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist}
```

and have also tried

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="members" status="not closed" dynamic="no"}

     {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But each time it only outputs 3 members out of 15. The members it does output are guests and super admins - it won't output any member of the default Members group.

Any body come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's happening here.

I'm also using transcribe on this site and it somewhat hijacks the channel entries output. The entry ID needs to be in the `exp_transcribe_entries_languages` table to be output on the frontend.

All of the members that weren't outputting were added through a front end Zoo Visitor registration form but this wouldn't take into account the need to add the entry into this table.

Any that were outputting I had viewed/edited the entry in the CP, meaning Transcribe kicked in and sorted out the multilingual side of things.

**Solution**

Add `transcribe='disable'` to your channel entries or zoo visitor tag.